# If you leave a dungeon to save, does it reset its state?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I'm working on the Pitioss Ruins dungeon, but I'd rather not do it all in one day. Plus I'm getting paranoid that my PS4 will mysteriously shut off or something and I'll have to start over! Obviously, I can't save in the dungeon, but I think I can get back to the entrance without too much trouble. The question is, if I leave, save, then reload, will my progress in the dungeon be kept or reset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like leaving a dungeon will cause the monsters inside to be reset, unfortunately.

From [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/932981-final-fantasy-xv/74659246):

> I have revisited a couple of dungeons, all mechanics such as doors stayed open like I left them. The monsters respawned but aside from Hunts, I did not see the Dungeon Boss again.

However, since you're specifically asking about Pitioss Dungeon (which I had to look up), it seems that this is a platforming dungeon, rather than a battle-centered dungeon (like Costlemark). From [this thread regarding progress in Pitioss Dungeon](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFXV/comments/5hrs6q/does_your_progress_in_pitioss_dungeon_save_of_you/):

> The dungeon doesn't reset. You will have to be able to get back to where you were though so for example if you're at the angel part then leaving would be a bad idea.
>
> I left at the moving devil platform thing. Saved, did a bunch of other stuff and came back to finish the next day. Just had to do a few jumps to get back there. All doors were still open.
>
> You will NOT return to your checkpoint inside the dungeon.

So it looks like doors will stay open, but you'll have to manually get back to where you were when you left to save.

Comment: Thank god. My joystick is apparently not up to precision platforming (it keeps getting stuck forward after I let go), which makes this dungeon especially infuriating. I'm going to try it. You better be right!

Comment: @Kat were you able to confirm this behavior?

Comment: Not yet. I left the dungeon at 5 am and got bored waiting for it to turn night again. I'll let you know as soon I do.

Comment: Just confirmed that you're right and it saves the state. Yay!

Comment: @Kat glad to hear I didn't make you waste your time! :D